# Connect to multiple redis ports via redis-cli

Tags: redis

does anyone know how I can connect and query from multiple redis ports? I know that I can connect to one server on one port via:

`redis-cli -h servername -p portNumber`

However, I can't find in the documentation how to connect to multiple ports (i have 4 ports total). Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't - launch a different cli tattoo each port. The cli tool doesn't do multiple connections.